# Farming or harvesting votes?

Tags: discussion, meta

What happens if/when somebody decides to get a friend who votes for all their posts and vice/versa? Would that be bad?

Comment: No system is without flaw, if that person is satisfy with getting more votes rather than improving his or her knowledge when posting on worldbuilding that's fine as long as nobody is hurt.

Comment: So if someone seems to have an abnormal upvote count on a large number of mundane posts, presumably from "fans", the pattern is seen by moderators and (if left in place) is vetted as honest?

Comment: I would again ask that you would upvote the question if you like the answers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It's bad if it's dishonest.**

Because we, society, have agreed that being dishonest is bad. However, if the two people legitimately like the other person's posts for whatever reason then it's not bad.

The obvious extension would be creating a second account to vote for all your posts. That's bad. It's inherently dishonest.

In either case it is ultimately pointless. These are *internet points*. You can't spend them and falsely inflating them will not give anyone a sense of accomplishment.

Comment: Plus a voting streak would be detected and revoked. And it can only go so far to boost you. Consider that some active user will get to like 40-60 posts (I know the most active have more, but they are more exceptions than rule). So you'd gain what 500 reputation points? That's not helping you overpassing @Samuel :)

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin 40 posts is the max in one day and about 1/3 of those have to be upvotes on questions.  If you only upvote answers you max at 30

Answer (score 9):

Moderators can see the voting behavior of users. Although they can't see the specific details of each vote, they have the metadata. Furthermore, if you up-vote too many posts of the same user in a short time, the system can undo it automatically under certain conditions: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

If it's done in good faith, you should not have problems if you give a handful of votes now and then. Still, I would encourage you to upvote: not just your friend's posts but all the posts you consider useful as well.

Comment: Excellent link.